# How many ratings required for iTunes average rating?

Tags: iphone, itunes

I have tried to search all over for this, but have not succeeded in finding an answer unfortunately..

Apps on the iTunes app store show average ratings when enough ratings are received. Does anyone have a ballpark on how many ratings are required for an average rating? New apps display "Not enough ratings" until some threshold is reached. I emailed Apple, but they are slow..

Comment: This is not a programming question, but one about the internal functioning of the iTunes store.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It is 5. I've watched apps tick from 4 to 5 reviews, and that's when it happens.

Comment: It is 5 totally from all countries? Or to show up an average rating in the US, do I need 5 ratings from the US?

Comment: @NicHubbard I believe it's per-country.

Answer (score 11):

I believe it is 5. Just anecdotal experience to back this up though.

Answer (score 1):

5 reviews per country.
You can see reviews in app store of specific country if your app has received at least 5 ratings from that country.