# How many reviews does an iOS app need before all reviews are included in the average?

Tags: app-store, itunes

When you release a new update of an iPhone app, iTunes temporarily stops including reviews from old versions while it waits for users to submit enough reviews of the latest update. Eventually, it starts to include all reviews when calculating your average and displaying your total review count.

When does this transition take place? Do you need to reach a certain number of reviews? If so, what is that number?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about proprietary app store policies.

Answer (score 14):

It's 5 (ratings, comments are options).
While I say this from personal experience on various app, it's impossible to find an official information about this, but this value is confirmed by [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373308/how-many-ratings-required-for-itunes-average-rating).

Comment: I noticed that too - it takes five reviews to go from "No reviews" to the point where it shows you a score. However, there seems to be another threshold where it will only show reviews specifically from the latest version for a period of time. Then, eventually, it starts averaging in all of your reviews.